# Что быстрее: обход вектора или обход списка?

Tags: c++, list, оптимизация, vector, stl

На собеседовании спросили: что быстрее, обход вектора или обход списка с выводом значений в консоль? Каким образом обходим, не уточнили. Я ответил, что разницы нет. Был ли я прав?
Пояснение: имеется контейнер вектор, по которому мы пробегаемся, например, итератором:

```
std::vector<int> vector{1, 2, 3};
for (auto it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it)
{
    qDebug() << *it;
}
```

имеется контейнер список, по которому мы также пробегаемся итератором:

```
std::list<int> values{1, 2, 3};
for (auto it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it)
{
    qDebug() << *it;
}
```

Какой из циклов будет работать быстрее и почему?
Какой из циклов будет работать быстрее при других способах обхода этих контейнеров?
Этих циклов не было на собеседовании, я их добавил для наглядности.

P.S. После этого вопроса затем спросили: что такое кэш? Возможно, второй вопрос как-то связан с первым? Если весь вектор или список не попадает в кэш, то время обхода контейнера увеличится?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Вектор несколько быстрее - за счет двух факторов:

1. в нем нет переходов по указателям, нет лишних разыменований
2. в нем нет переходов по указателям - все лежит одной кучей, а значит, с высокой степенью локальности, так что высока вероятность, что все содержимое вектора разместится в кеше процессора (а если и не все из-за очень большого вектора - то большими кусками), т.е. с существенно более высокой скоростью, чем *в общем случае* в списке, где элементы могут быть разбросаны по всей памяти...

P.S. Раз уж этот вопрос всплыл заново :) - измерим.

Миллионный список и вектор. Сортировка - чтоб в списке побольше случайных переходов в разные места памяти было.

```
list<int> L;
vector<int> V;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        int r = rand();
        V.push_back(r);
        L.push_back(r);
    }
    L.sort();
    sort(V.begin(),V.end());

    {
        muTimer mu;
        long long int sum = 0;
        for(int i: V) sum += i;
        mu.stop();
        cout << "Sum " << sum << " for " << mu.duration() << " mks\n";
    }
    {
        muTimer mu;
        long long int sum = 0;
        for(int i: L) sum += i;
        mu.stop();
        cout << "Sum " << sum << " for " << mu.duration() << " mks\n";
    }

}
```

Полный код - [здесь](https://ideone.com/cg7H5J). Как видим, разница практически в 200 раз в пользу вектора... Так что "несколько быстрее" - это я преуменьшил :)

Comment: спасибо за прояснение!

Comment: Так подправьте ответ, заменив *несколько* на *пару порядков* (заранее плюсую)

Comment: @avp Не могу :) - потому что я ее получал не то чтобы искусственно, но... Например, при малых размерах разница будет не столь существенной. Или если убрать сортировку (которая просто перемешивает местоположения элементов в списке) - то разница сразу падает до примерно в 30 раз. Так что оставим неопределенное "несколько" :)

Comment: @Harry, сортировка вектора вытесняет из кеша элементы списка и сама прогревает кеш в пользу вектора. В результате вектор тестируется на кешированной памяти. Список тестируется на не кешированной памяти. Это объясняет колебания в производительности. Корректнее прогревать кеши повторяя суммирование несколько раз, но время измерять только в последний.

Answer (score 11):

Для вопроса "обход вектора или обход списка с выводом значений в консоль" -  правильный ответ это "одинаково, т.к. время обхода пренебрежимо мало по сравнению со временем записи в консоль".

Что касается времени итерации и чтения элементов, то обход списка может быть значительно медленнее если его элементы расположены в памяти в произвольном порядке.

Расходы на разыменование указателей на следующие элементы списка незначительны по сравнению со временем на работу с элементами списка.

Answer (score 7):

Это коварный многослойный вопрос. Получив его, можно поумничать.

1. С точки зрения математики ассимптотически скорость равна: O(N). Разница в обоих случаях определяется коэффициентом перед N, который зависит от скорости конкретных операций: разыменование, чтение, вывод и так далее. Константой можно пренебречь, но вообще-то она тоже есть.
2. С точки зрения доступа к элементам с учётом аппаратуры быстрее будет вектор, потому что кэш процессора оптимизирован для доступа к последовательным блокам памяти, а не потенциально разбросанным по всей памяти небольшим элементам.
3. С практической точки зрения доступ к консоли — несоразмеримо медленная операция относительно всех остальных, поэтому скорость будет определяться ей. Соответственно, разница между вектором и списком будет пренебрежимо мала.
4. В качестве особенного выпендрёжа рассказываем про возможность использования кастомных аллокаторов у коллекций STL, что делает рассуждения о скорости невалидными, так как мы можем для хранения данных использовать устройство, которое не даёт преимущества последовательному доступу. Скажем, делаем маппинг памяти на файл с файловой системой без кэша...

В этот момент у собеседующего пропадает желание с сами разговаривать.

Answer (score 3):

Если глянуть глубже, получится что у вектора все элементы хранятся в непрерывном участке памяти, и он может поместиться в кэш. При этом сама операция обхода может быть немного быстрее у вектора, т.к. там просто сдвиг. Но если вам действительно интересно, проведите тестирование на 10000000 элементах, например.

Comment: спасибо, что прояснили. да, попробую потестировать